# Android Studio native cpu profiler support thread time

Tags: android-studio-arctic-fox, android-studio-4.2

Android Studio Version: 4.2.2
Describe:

1. Android Studio, open Project with Native code
2. Start up application on Mobile, and then Use profile
3. Select CPU profiling mode : Sample C/C++ Functions
4. after a moment, I can see each thread's 'Top Down' tab

but it is wall clock time and it can not  change to cpu time or 'thread time' as following picture:

How can I change it to 'Thread time' or how can I profile the hot function that consume cpu

[image]